# Sort data.frame or data.table using vector of column names

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, data.table

I have a `data.frame` (a `data.table` in fact) that I need to sort by multiple columns. The names of columns to sort by are in a vector. How can I do it? E.g.

```
DF <- data.frame(A= 5:1, B= 11:15, C= c(3, 3, 2, 2, 1))
DF
  A  B C
  5 11 3
  4 12 3
  3 13 2
  2 14 2
  1 15 1

sortby <- c('C', 'A')

DF[order(sortby),] ## How to do this?
```

The desired output is the following but using the `sortby` vector as input.

```
DF[with(DF, order(C, A)),]
  A  B C
  1 15 1
  2 14 2
  3 13 2
  4 12 3
  5 11 3
```

(Solutions for `data.table` are preferable.)

**EDIT**: I'd rather avoid importing additional packages provided that base R or data.table don't require too much coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
setorderv(DF, sortby)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > DF
>    A  B C
> 1: 1 15 1
> 2: 2 14 2
> 3: 3 13 2
> 4: 4 12 3
> 5: 5 11 3
> ```

For completeness, with `setorder`:

```
setorder(DF, C, A)
```

The advantage of using `setorder`/`setorderv` is that the data is reordered by reference and thus very fast and memory efficient. Both functions work on `data.table`'s as wel as on `data.frame`'s.

---

If you want to combine ascending and descending ordering, you can use the `order`-parameter of `setorderv`:

```
setorderv(DF, sortby, order = c(1L, -1L))
```

which subsequently gives:

> ```
> > DF
>    A  B C
> 1: 1 15 1
> 2: 3 13 2
> 3: 2 14 2
> 4: 5 11 3
> 5: 4 12 3
> ```

With `setorder` you can achieve the same with:

```
setorder(DF, C, -A)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, you can use `arrange_at` which accepts string column names :

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% arrange_at(sortby)

#  A  B C
#1 1 15 1
#2 2 14 2
#3 3 13 2
#4 4 12 3
#5 5 11 3
```

Or with the new version

```
DF %>% arrange(across(sortby))
```

---

In base R, we can use

```
DF[do.call(order, DF[sortby]), ]
```

Comment: Can it be done with base R or data.table without too much coding? I'd rather avoid an additional dependency...

Comment: Added an option with base R.

Comment: I'm going to accept @Jaap's answer but thanks for that. The `do.call` solution is really cool.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with `dplyr`:

```
DF %>%
    arrange(get(sort_by))
```

But Ronaks answer is more elegant.